# Limit and Convergence of Doob Martingales

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P})$ be a probability space for $X\in L^1(\mathcal{P})$ and $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ a filtration. Then $$Y_n = \mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_n)$$ is called Doob Martingale. The class of Doob Martingales are uniformly integrable and together convergence in probability, by Vitali's convergence theorem, they converge in $L^1$. Many things imply convergence in probablity, e.g. $L^1$ boundedness implies convergence almost surely by Doob's convergence theorem, which in turn implies convergence in probability.

The the limit is $Y_\infty = \mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_\infty)$, where $\mathcal{F}_\infty = \sigma( \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}_n)$.

My question is, does it hold that $Y_\infty = X$  almost surely for any filtration, or do we require $ \mathcal{F}_n\nearrow  \mathcal{F}$?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out, $Y_{\infty} = \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal F_\infty]$.  In order to have $X = Y_\infty = \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal F_\infty]$, we would of course require that $X$ is $\mathcal F_\infty$ measurable.  That doesn't necessarily mean that we need $\mathcal F_\infty = \mathcal F$, just that $\sigma(X) \subseteq \mathcal F_\infty$.

As a example to show $Y_\infty$ may not be $X$, one could take the trivial filtration $\mathcal F_n = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ for all $n$.  Then $Y_\infty = Y_n = \mathbb{E}[X]$, which is not equal to $X$ for any non-constant random variable.

As an example to show we don't necessarily need $\mathcal F_\infty = \mathcal F$, one can take $X$ and $Z$ to be two independent non-trivial random variables, $\mathcal F = \sigma(X,Z)$, and $\mathcal F_n = \sigma(X)$ for all $n$.  Then $\mathcal F_\infty = \sigma(X) \ne \mathcal F$, but $Y_\infty = X$.

Comment: Can we generalize that for $Y_\infty = X$  a.s. we need only $\sigma(X)\subset \mathcal{F}_\infty$, purely from definition of $Y_\infty$ as conditional expectation?

Comment: @Sussyphus Note that $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal F_\infty]$ is $\mathcal F_\infty$ measurable by the definition of conditional expectation.  If $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal F_\infty] = X$ a.s., that implies $X$ is $\mathcal F_\infty$ measurable (maybe need completeness of $\mathcal F_\infty$ here), so $\sigma(X) \subset \mathcal F_\infty$.  The fact that $\sigma(X) \subset \mathcal F_\infty$ implies $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal F_\infty] = X$ also follows readily from the definition of conditional expectation.